# Uniform approximation to indicator by bounded continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to establish a sequence of bounded continuous function $I_n(x)$, $n\geq1$ so that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x}|I_n(x) - I(x)| =0,
$$

where $I(x) = {\bf1}_{(a,+\infty)}(x)$ is an indicator on the open set $(a,+\infty)$. Here $a>0$?

Comment: Do you remember a theorem about the limit function of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions?

Comment: Thanks. I realize that $I(x)$ is not continuous, and hence it is impossible to find thus $I_n(x)$.